# Cakephp 3.4 - Usage of setMatching() and getMatching()

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.4

I have upgraded to CakePHP 3.4 and I’m checking through the 3.4 deprecation list, the migration guide says *getMatching() will have to be called after setMatching() to keep the old behavior*  I'm confused and couldn’t find any documentation on sample on setMatching() and getMatching() functions. How or where should I declare setMatching(). Can anybody please point out to me how do I rewrite the below code using setMatching and getMatching:

```
TableRegistry::get('Students')->find()
        ->distinct([ 'Students.id'])
        ->matching('Studentclassrooms.Classrooms',
              function ($q) use ( $classid ){
                   return $q->where([ 'Classrooms.id' => $classid ]);
              });
        ->enableAutoFields(true);
```

When I tried the below, I get the error

> Unknown method "setMatching”

```
TableRegistry::get('Students')->find()
        ->distinct([ 'Students.id'])
        ->setMatching('Studentclassrooms.Classrooms',
              function ($q) use ( $classid ){
                    return $q->where([ 'Classrooms.id' => $classid ]);
              })
        ->getMatching()
        ->enableAutoFields(true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a closer look at the migration guide (currently down, appears to be issues with the hoster), `\Cake\ORM\Query::matching()` is not deprecated, it's `\Cake\ORM\EagerLoader::matching()` that is (which in turn is used internall in `\Cake\ORM\Query::matching()`), there are no `\Cake\ORM\Query::setMatching()/getMatching()` methods, but `\Cake\ORM\EagerLoader::setMatching()/getMatching()`.

Having to call `getMatching()` after `setMatching()` is because unlike `matching('Alias')`, which will return an array of containments, `setMatching('Alias')` will set up the matching stuff, but return `$this` instead. So in order to retrieve the array of prepared containments, you'd have to call `getMatching()` afterwards.

Long story short, nothing in your example needs to be rewritten.

- **[Source > 3.4 Migration Guide > Deprecations > Deprecated Combined Get/Set Methods](https://github.com/cakephp/docs/blob/3.0/en/appendices/3-4-migration-guide.rst#deprecated-combined-getset-methods)**
- **[Source > \Cake\ORM\Query::matching()](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.4.0/src/ORM/Query.php#L474)**
- **[Source > \Cake\ORM\EagerLoader::matching()](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.4.0/src/ORM/EagerLoader.php#L279)**
- **[Source > \Cake\ORM\EagerLoader::setMatching()](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.4.0/src/ORM/EagerLoader.php#L218)**
- **[Source > \Cake\ORM\EagerLoader::getMatching()](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.4.0/src/ORM/EagerLoader.php#L252)**

Comment: Thank you for your help!